# "Type class is not known to the MapperRegistry" in MyBatis

Tags: mybatis, ibatis

## My Problem

I'm getting the error `Type class myPackage.MyClass is not known to the MapperRegistry`.

I successfully acquired a session, and upon debugging I can see that it otherwise appears to be configured correctly so the interface association seems to be working; therefor I'm confident this error is distinct from the stack-overflow-suggested `Type interface is not known...` question.

I'm new to myBatis but from the documentation I understood that the following was all that was required to get resultType auto-mapping to work.

Update: This also happens when mapping the mapper resources by xml file instead of by class.

## My  Mapper

```
public interface MyClassMapper{
    MyClass getMyClass(Integer id);
}
```

## My Model

```
public class MyClass{
    private String itemValue;

    public String getItemValue() {
        return itemValue;
    }

    public void setItemValue(String itemValue) {
        this.itemValue = itemValue;
    }
}
```

## My Sql Map

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN" "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd" >
<mapper namespace="myPackage.orm.sqlMap.MyClassMapper" >

    <select id="getMyClass" resultType="myPackage.MyClass" >
     select itemValue 
     from SOME_TABLE 
     WHERE id = #{id}
    </select> 
</mapper>
```

## My mybatis-config.xml

```
 ...
 <mappers>
      <mapper class="myPackage.MyClass" />
 </mappers>
 ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed:

```
    public MyClass getMyClassValue(Integer id) throws Exception{
         SqlSession session = MyBatisSessionFactory.openSession();
         MyClassMapper mapper = (MyClassMapper) session.getMapper(MyClass.class);
         return mapper.getMyClass(id);
     }
```

Here is the code I was using to execute the query, discovered that I was looking up the mapper in the mapper registry by the model class name, rather than the mapper interface name. Works just fine now.

Answer (score 0):

In your mapper.xml file mapper's namespace should be the path to the mapper interface.

for example:

```
<mapper namespace="com.mapper.LineMapper">
<select id="selectLine" resultType="com.jiaotong114.jiaotong.beans.Line">
select * from bus_line where id = #{id}
</select>
</mapper>
```

your mapper interface should be in com.mapper package and the name of it is LineMapper.

hope help.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by adding the mapper XML to the mybatis xml configuration file

```
  <mappers>    
    <mapper resource="com/java/Mapper.xml"/>
  </mappers>
```